# Move all *.mp4 files from all subfolders to another specified folder

Tags: bash, terminal

The parent directory has 5 sub folders, each subfolder has .mp4s, .txt, and other file extensions, how to be in the parents folder and enter a terminal command to only pull all *.mp4s into another specified folder in Bash.

Answer (score 3):

I stand in the specified parent directory and move the files to the other specified folder that I assume is `../other-spec-dir` ( a folder that is not in the search path of `find`)

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp4s" -exec mv {} ../other-spec-dir \;
```

Note that if there are files with identical name only the last one will survive.

Answer (score 2):

`find /path/to/src -type f -name “*.mp4” | xargs -iF mv F /path/to/dst`

Comment: thank you, I was looking for something that I could specify the file extension and this as it.